# Android Wear notifications: full screen

Tags: android, wear-os

I want to create such kind of a notification (like [here](http://developer.android.com/design/wear/structure.html), in Breaking out of the card (with custom layouts) section). That is, it shoud contain a full screen page (in fact, with a map).

Is it (on a picture) an extended notification or a wear app? How to implement this full screen view?

I have tried doing as described [here](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/layouts.html), but my activity is not starting from a notification.

Answer (score 2):

You can embed an Activity into a Wear Notification like so:

```
Notification myFullScreenNotification = new Notification.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentText(notificationText)
        .extend(new Notification.WearableExtender()
                .setCustomSizePreset(Notification.WearableExtender.SIZE_FULL_SCREEN)
                .setDisplayIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MyActivity.class), 0)))
        .build();
```

Make sure you give the right permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:allowEmbedded="true"
    android:taskAffinity="" />
```

The notification shows normally until the user swipes upwards, then it will turn into fullscreen and run the activity on the page.

If you want to use the Activity as a secondary page of the Notification, then insert the Notification above as a page of another notification like so:

```
Notification myWearNotification = new Notification.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentText(notificationText)
        .extend(new Notification.WearableExtender()
                .addPage(myFullScreenNotification)
        .build();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. Maybe that's because I'm using the NotificationCompat library (not Notification), but I'm not sure. The excerpts have no effect. just nothing happens. Any clue?

Comment: There's no need to use the NotificationCompat library, since this code should be run on a wearable app not a handheld app. I don't think that there is a way to do this directly from the handheld app. I think you need to make a wearable app and launch the notification from there.

Comment: So that's the question. It's not an app, I want to extend notifications in this way. By the way, after some research, it seems to me that it's not possible and the only way to full screen is an app that I don't need.

Comment: If it's the only way to achieve what you want to do then you do need it!

Comment: Have you tested this code? Because I'm doing something very similar and having problems with getting the icon to show up on the peeking notification. If I do it like you suggest it only shows the contentTitle. If i set icon on the WearableExtender the icon shows, but the view is not large enough to fit it (it's abnormally small, seems to be adjusted to only fit the title). I created another question actually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441662/how-to-add-an-icon-on-a-peeking-custom-android-wearable-notification

Answer (score 0):

An Android Wear app is required to fully customise the layout of a notification.

I tried coding a custom library which ships a layout xml from the phone to wear and inflate but that's not possible because of limitations relating to [LayoutInflator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).

Here's the relevant bit for reference: *For performance reasons, view inflation relies heavily on pre-processing of XML files that is done at build time. Therefore, it is not currently possible to use LayoutInflater with an XmlPullParser over a plain XML file at runtime; it only works with an XmlPullParser returned from a compiled resource (R.something file.)*