# How to add an icon on a peeking custom android wearable notification?

Tags: android, notifications, android-wear-notification

Our custom notification only shows title (or content text if title is missing) when it's peeking. Trying to set the icon on the root notification has no effect. If I set the icon on the extender notification it shows, but the peeking notification is so small (obviously, its height is fitted to the height of the one liner title/description) that the icon wont fit. In comparison to e.g. an email notification the height of the peeking notification is much smaller.

Here's the outline of the code I'm trying to run:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, CustomNotification.class);
PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
    notificationIntent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Test")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .extend(new Notification.WearableExtender()
                                .setDisplayIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
                                .setCustomSizePreset(Notification.WearableExtender.SIZE_FULL_SCREEN)
                )
                .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be running into that fact that you have very little control over how the notification displays while in peek-view:

"Note: When the notification is peeking on the homescreen, the system displays it with a standard template that it generates from the notification's semantic data. This template works well on all watchfaces. When users swipe the notification up, they'll then see the custom activity for the notification."

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/layouts.html#UiLibrary

Comment: I guess that may be it. Then again why do they offer this possibility to use fully customised notifications if in practice they can't be used because when peeking they then look ridiculous?

Comment: I think the idea is that you use the standard peek view as a title for your content, then they swipe up on it to view that custom content. The peek is meant to consume information extremely quickly and unobtrusively so to put a lot of attention grabbing custom content there would go against design guidlines

Comment: Can you elaborate on that a bit? It sounds like that's exactly what I want to do. I'm trying to get my notification show up the same way as the standard notifications when peeking and when user swipes it up then show my custom view, but I do not see any obvious way to "use the standard peek view as the title for" my pending notification.